# Error in getView method of ImageAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

I am firing the rawQuery for selectin the gender.If gender is male then male photo should get deployed on dashboard.But i am getting error "NullPointerEcxeption" in rawQuery statement.
Could you please help me out there? Thanks.

My getView function in ImageAdapter is

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);;
    HashMap<String, Integer> images = new HashMap<String, Integer>();    
    images.put( "male", Integer.valueOf( R.drawable.kidmale));
    images.put( "female", Integer.valueOf( R.drawable.kidfemale));    
    //String select="SELECT gender FROM db_mydata.tbl_mykid";
    Cursor res=db.rawQuery("SELECT gender FROM tbl_mykid " ,new String[]{gender}); 
    while(res.moveToNext())
    {
        String s=res.getColumnName(3);
        if(s=="male")
        {
            imageView.setImageResource( images.get( "male").intValue() );
        }
        else  
        {
            imageView.setImageResource( images.get( "female" ).intValue() ); 
        }
    }
    if (convertView == null) 
    {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } 
    else 
    {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}   
// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {R.drawable.add,};
```

Answer (score 2):

After the `rawQuery` statement put following line in your code

```
res.moveToFirst()
```

Comment: are you sure that there is data in your db otherwise you have to implement check for that also

Comment: I have data in my db.But here i am using hashmap & insert the default image (i.e R.drawable.....) accordingly.